# how send value when press back button flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, appbar

I have a simple code

```
class A_View extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<A_ViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => A_ViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, model.value)),
        ),
        body: model.isBusy
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                .............
                ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class A_ViewModel extends FutureViewModel {
   int value = 10;
}
```

when i click button back in appbar . i was get value form pop
but when i click back button on my phone -> value is null
how to back button on my phone return value same button in appbar ?, please help me

Comment: this is a problem with state management. Although you can do Navigator.push().then((value){ code here}); It's still better to properly manage your state. I recommend starting with provider then moving off to bloc: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Answer (score 1):

To get the value from the back button pressed on your phone, you can use the willPopScope widget. Have a look into the below code:

```
return ViewModelBuilder<A_ViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => A_ViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => WillPopScope(
        //here you can do the magic
          onWillPop: ()async{
            Navigator.pop(context, model.value);
            return Future<bool>.value(false);
          },
          child:Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, model.value)),
            ),
            body: model.isBusy
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ListView.builder(
            .............
            ),
          )
      )
    );
```

Comment: i not get model.vaue if WillPopScope the above

Comment: edited the answer, hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I met error when return flase in onWillPop: ()
The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future<bool>', as required by the closure's context